# Create assignment with file drive using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-developers-console, google-classroom

I'm a new developer, I want to add an assignment in Google Classroom using a script. Here is the code that was created:

```
function assignmentWithDriveFile(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ASSIGNMENT (Drive File)');
  const courseId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const topicId = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue.toString();

  var assignment = {
    topicId: topicId,
    title: sheet.getRange('B3').getValue().toString(),
    description: sheet.getRange('B4').getValue().toString(),
    materials :[{
      driveFile: {
        driveFile: {
          id: sheet.getRange('B5').getValue.toString(),
          title: sheet.getRange('B6').getValue.toString()
        },
        shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
      }
    }],
    maxPoints : sheet.getRange('B7').getValue().toString(),
    state: "PUBLISHED",
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
  };

  const newCourseAssignment = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(assignment, courseId);
  const assId = newCourseAssignment.id;
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue(assId);
}
```

after running I get a notification in my spreadsheet that is "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.create failed with error: @AttachmentNotVisible The item referenced by an attachment was not found or not visible to the user."
well what should i do?
I really wait for your answer and I appreciate it```

Do I have to change the drive ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About the error of `The item referenced by an attachment was not found or not visible to the user.`, in this case, when the file ID is the invalid file ID, such an error occurs. When I saw your showing script, I thought that at `id: sheet.getRange('B5').getValue.toString(),`, `getValue` should be `getValue()`. This can be also seen at `title: sheet.getRange('B6').getValue.toString()`. If your file ID is correct, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to this.
- In your situation, I think that the values can be retrieved from cells `B1:B7` by one call.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function assignmentWithDriveFile() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ASSIGNMENT (Drive File)');
  const [[courseId], [topicId], [title], [description], [driveFileId], [driveFileTitle], [maxPoints]] = sheet.getRange("B1:B7").getDisplayValues();
  var assignment = {
    topicId,
    title,
    description,
    materials: [{
      driveFile: {
        driveFile: {
          id: driveFileId, title: driveFileTitle
        },
        shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
      }
    }],
    maxPoints: maxPoints,
    state: "PUBLISHED",
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
  };
  const newCourseAssignment = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(assignment, courseId);
  const assId = newCourseAssignment.id;
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue(assId);
}
```

- I think that when these values of `[[courseId], [topicId], [title], [description], [driveFileId], [driveFileTitle], [maxPoints]]` are correct values, this script works.

Comment: hi, thanks for the very fast answer, I've corrected my code following the code you provided. thanks for the answer i can get the assId i need! Once again, thank you

Comment: @Putri Zukhruf Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.